# Scheduling missions using the Mobile-SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

Is it possible to create a Waypoint mission using the mobile SDK and schedule it to run at a certain time every day?

Once the mission has been created and loaded onto the drone using a mobile app, I would like the drone to fly missions without any user intervention.

Is this possible using the Mobile SDK? If not would it be possible to implement using either the Onboard SDK or Windows SDK?

Answer (score 0):

For both MSDK and OSDK it is possible. WSDK I doubt if it can be used for petrol

For MSDK just get Date date=cal. getTime();.  If the time is the time you want to do plan the mission using this class e.g

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/tree/master/Sample%20Code/app/src/main/java/com/dji/sdk/sample/demo/missionmanager

For OSDK is using PC, So in PC there is no such thing as can not. Put the sdk.launch in PC auto startup script.

and have the PC system monitoring the time using python. If time reached, using the python system call to call a script which contains ros source and rosrun

```
rosrun dji_sdk_demo demo_mission
```

Change the mission to the waypoint you want it to be. Although it is planned in OSDK, the phone android side will also be updated.

But before you do that, do have a drone-box ready. Drone box means 24-7-365 auto charging and auto cleaning station. Here I can not promote any commercial thing and there is not any option outthere, if you need it, let me know. I have a similar prototype.

Comment: Hey man, apologise for the delayed reply. I am really interested in this drone-box. Do you have a skype-id I can contact you on?

Comment: Im sorry to disappoint you but I was told just now not to share prototype information in public yet.  The final product will be available at this DJI dealer site https://www.avetics.com/ in later this year or early next year.  If you need it urgently, a similar project can be found in delftdynamics  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfZhtyMOlJE&t=4s . However their`s is manual box so you have to add a lot of things to get it full automated for DJI drone. Not sure if they are willing to customize it for you or not because they don't use DJI and they have their own custom systems.

Comment: For the software it is easy to implement, I can help you write a script to autorun this fix time petrol process.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as noted above it is possible but the implementation will not be as you describe; what I mean is that you cannot upload the mission and leave the aircraft to start the mission at he prescribed time.

You can create an app (using any of the SDKs) and have the app monitor the system clock and at the designated time of day the app can upload and start the flight.

Issues I see with this is that you will either need a way to keep the aircraft charged while sitting idle or a method to power on the controller and aircraft.  Using a Wi-Fi/Bluetooth connection would remove the need for the controller but the aircraft will still need to be powered in order to receive the mission commands.

Good luck